# Parameter specified as non-null is null exception, using gson on web api return null

Tags: android, api, android-studio, kotlin, gson

How to prevent gson from recieving null object from web api

when Web api return null

> { "events": null }

it will become this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
```

Gson usage

```
val data = gson.fromJson(apiRepository
                .doRequest(TheSportDBApi.getLatestMatch(league)),
                MatchResponse::class.java)
```

My data class

```
data class MatchResponse (val events: List<Match>)
```

Match.class

```
data class Match(
    @SerializedName("idEvent")
    var eventId: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("strDate")
    var matchDate: String? = null,


    //home
    @SerializedName("strHomeTeam")
    var homeTeam: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("intHomeScore")
    var homeScore: String? = null,

    var homeBadger:String?=null,


    //away
    @SerializedName("strAwayTeam")
    var awayTeam: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("intAwayScore")
    var awayScore: String? = null,

    var awayBadge: String? = null
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your event variable of the MatchResponse class nullable? Something like:

```
val event: Event?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make that particular object `nullable` using `?` in `kotlin`

```
data class Article(
     val title: String, 
     val body: String, 
     val events: Events? = null, //Make it nullable
     val payWall: Boolean = false, 
     val titleImage: String? = null
)
```