# Null safety issues with Gson in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, nullpointerexception, gson, deserialization, kotlin-null-safety

I have a data class:

```
data class Temp(
        val value: Int
    )
```

When I run the following code:

```
 val temp1 = Gson().fromJson("", Temp::class.java)
 val temp2 = temp1.value
 println(temp2)
```

I get null pointer exception.

Doesn't this violate the null safety of kotlin?

Comment: there are already other posts regarding this issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52272314/parameter-specified-as-non-null-is-null-exception-using-gson-on-web-api-return, but no, not really, it has to do with the way gson does deserialization, mark everything as potentially nullable or hope it's true

Comment: Null safety is achieved at compile-time, but in your case error happens at runtime

Comment: Yes, and that's called a [platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types).

Comment: @Sweeper.. Thanks a lot for the clarification. I did search for ! vs ? in kotlin and wasn't able to find much info regarding it. I did assume it has to do with java variables being nullable and didn't know 'platform type' is the correct terminology for such variables.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember, this has to do with the way that GSON makes use of reflection, which essentially can bypass kotlin null-safety, so the best thing you can do is mark all fields as potentially nullable and be safe, alternatively you could consider writing custom type adapters too, but that could be a bit much, as this null safety is only really valid for compile-time, but isn't really guaranteed during runtime

---

Generally, if you're making use of a third-party api which can change at any time, it's probably a good idea to consider the fact that stuff could be changed at any given time, changes in variable names or variables being removed, etc. If you're using your own api's, this is probably a bit different, as you'd (hopefully) have more control over the change, still doesn't hurt to manually implement null-safety though, assume everything can be null

Comment: So am I supposed to manually declare temp1 as:
val temp1: Temp? = Gson().fromJson("", Temp::class.json)

Comment: @DikenMhrz Yes, explicitly declaring it as nullable would be safe.

Comment: that would work if you suspect temp1 could potentially not be created as the result of the gson parse, but also take into account variables inside your class being null, so  `data class Temp(val value: Int? )`